# How to test a method in non-public class ? I think it's NOT the same to test the private or protected method in a public class

Tags: java, unit-testing

My question is about test a method in non-public class.  I'm not the developer,  but a unit tester.

I think I know how to test a private and protected method in a public class.   reflection or write your own subclass.

Maybe is there any way to test a method in a non-public class?  Some class is written to be non-pubilic,  is able to test it?

Pre-condition: I don't have rights to  write test class in the same package with the class tested.

Any comments will be appreciated, thanks.

Code:

```
package com.whoistester.a;
class a {  // non-public class

    public void methodA()
    {
    }

}

package com.whoistester.test
public class test {

    public void testa()
    {
       // here how to test the method of the class a ???
    }

}
```

**Solutions:**
How dumb am I. It's easy to do this.  Different projects but junit test and  tested code both could be in the same package.
    project/src/main/com/tec/Util.java 
    test-project/src/test/com/tec/UtilTest.java

Comment: Can you not instantiate the class using reflection and call the methods?

Comment: As the class is not public, it must be used by other classes in the same package. If you can get the instance of this class by calling some method of other class using it, I guess you can write test cases for it.

Comment: it is **default** instead of private, public or protected. visible with in package.

Comment: Still it has to be used internally in the package. Or else the class is useless.

Comment: @kal, Can NOT instantiate , don't have right to.

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag ,  That , Do u know , How to write the testcase outsite the package for it ?

Comment: @nighteblis Although I have not tried it, if one can set final fields using reflection, there must be a way to instantiate classes with default scope. Are you constrained with some security policy?

Comment: @nighteblis : I think you must try to get the instance of this class by calling a method from some other class (public) using it. Once you have the instance you can call the methods and test it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't want to write test class in the same package with the class tested?

Well, in my projects, I usually put the test classes in a different physical directory, but the same package as the classes they test, and this is also the structure that Maven promotes:

For example:

`project/src/main/com/tec/Util.java`

`project/src/test/com/tec/UtilTest.java'`

Organizing test code in this structure allows the test code to access package private fields. And I can easily compile and package it separately so that production jar files do not contain test code.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: you may misunderstand the question.   Tej said "You can not access Class (Non Public) of One Package from the other package. Non Public Class is private for other package classes."

Comment: Hi, I got you. My suggestion is 'write test class in the same package with the class tested' but different directory. And this structure is also Maven's suggestion. Could you tell me why you set the 'pre-condtion : I don't want to write test class in the same package with the class tested.'?

Comment: How dumb am I. I'll revoke that condition.

Comment: As I don't have right to commit the code in the project. I'm not the developer and a unit tester.  Thanks Owen!
          ======================
    project/src/main/com/tec/Util.java   // this structure will work , and is what i wanted.       ======================                                                test-project/src/test/com/tec/UtilTest.java'

Answer (score 0):

You can not access Class (Non Public) of One Package from the other package. Non Public Class is private for other package classes.

Comment: thanks.  So Junit test can't cover the Non public class (If we write the case which is not locate at the same package of the non-public class). It's disppointed.